# Custom UITableView text for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview, truncate, ellipsis

I remember having read this in Apple's documentation but now I can't find it. My TableView row is getting cut off at the right, but I would like to display both the beginning and end of the text.  How do I truncate (add an ellipsis) the text at the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  myCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation;
```

Comment: says lineBreakMode is deprecated, should I ignore it?

Comment: The mode for for wrapping and truncating text in the cell. (Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Instead set the line-break mode attribute of the UILabel objects assigned to the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties.)